# Return Json_Encode content and display it in HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, post

I have a input which I want users to enter their e-mail address so they can subscribe to a newsletter. I have simple php code that performs certain checks and I can't seem to find a way to display text into a HTML div (error or success cases).

**This is my php code:**

```
// code above is left out for simplicity

$success = @mail($mailTo, $subject, $msg, $headers);

    if ($success) {
        // I think i got it wrong here ...?
        $json_arr = array( "type" => "success", "msg" => $successMsg );
        echo json_encode( $json_arr );
    } else {
        $json_arr = array( "type" => "error", "msg" => $errorMsg );
        echo json_encode( $json_arr );
    }
```

**This is the HTML code:**

```
<div class="newsletter_form2">
<form method="post" name="news" action="newsletter.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailNewsletter" id="emailNewsletter" required="required" placeholder="Vul je e-mail adres in">
            <button type="submit" title="Schrijf mij in" class="btn btn-default btn-radius" name="submit" value="Submit">schrijf mij in</button>

            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="alert-msg" class="alert-msg text-center"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

What am I missing here, any suggestions/directions?
Thank you!

Comment: ajax request and response?

Comment: Decide if you’re going to transport data as json or as html. If the former, you’ll generally fill in values using JavaScript to insert into the dom. If you use html, it’s simpler but you lose the ability to communicate information back to the Ajax function calling for it.

Comment: @TimMorton, what I want to achieve is returning text, so html would be OK. I don't know how to display something into HTML coming from a php file, can you advise me something so I know what to look into? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out JQuery's [getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Keep in mind you should set the corresponding Content-Type Header in PHP using `header("Content-Type: application/json);`. Using JQuery's [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) you can push the form data to the PHP script.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "yourUrl",
  data: $("#form").serialize(),
  success: function (result) {
     // handling your result
     $("#alert-msg").html(result.msg);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, I am aware of this kind of implementation but isn't it possible to do such thing with php -> html? I have the same setup (from a template i bought) for a contact form but when I "replicate" this it doesn't work. I am missing something but don't know what...

Comment: Did you include JQuery? Feel free to link your replication so I can take a look.

Comment: the contact form (which works) and the "subscribe to newsletter" part (which I am having issues) are in the same HTML page, the php scripts are 2 different files (contact.php & newsletter.php) where newsletter.php is a (simplified) copy of contact.php. So I would assume it has everything it needs. I am just totally not familiar with php at all. I will link the files later on, i'm on phone right now. THANK YOU SO MUCH for taking a look!

Comment: DrOpossum how do you want me to link the project? It's 1 html file, 2 php files and kind of a lot of CSS/JS.

Comment: @Dimitri here you go: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c42d10e3652e762f8e5865dc4b091e0f20190916143308/38099e

Comment: DrOpossum, what did you change so that I understand more and so that I can upload the proper (changed) files ?  Of course I will accept this as an answer ;)

Comment: In the `assets/scripts.js` I added the block with `$("#newsletterSubmit")` to trigger the Ajax function if the newsletter button is clicked. I also added the corresponding ids to the form elements & the submit button in the index.html :)

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed how I didn't think of that ... I love you :) I am getting a ParseError though when entering a valid email address. Will need to look into that further. But I guess that was the missing part ;) Thank you for pointing that out and changing it and for your time! Can you tell me this though, do you have any idea why after submitting the contact form, the placeholders are in English instead of the ones I have defined and are set before posting it? And Can I assume once I have the ParseError fixed, the success msg defined in the php file will be displayed in the HTML? Thank you again

Comment: @Dimitri yeah, if the parsing in the php file is working correctly it should display the returned success msg.

Comment: The parseError does not come from the php file, it sends the email but even when removing all code in php the error remains. I will have a look tonight.

Comment: OK so I commented out some of the added JS code block and the error is no more. I will look later what is exactly causing it. I still can't make it appear into the HTLM though, any ideas?

Comment: i have finally had to change things up, needed to use reCaptcha as well so I went and implemented this: https://themehunt.com/blog/28-web-tips-and-tricks/bootstrap-tips-and-tricks/168-how-to-add-recaptcha-to-bootstrap-contact-form which made me reconsider my previous code, all works good now. Thank you again!